# Swift - Keep the same instantiated UIViewController when switch tabs in TabbarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm writing an app with two or three main features. So I use Tabbarcontroller to switch between viewcontrollers (VC). The problem is, if I switch from VC1 to VC2, and then switch back to VC1, content of VC1 has changed when it moves from background to the foreground.
Does it mean that this is a newly instantiated VC, different from the VC1?
If so, how can I keep VC1 and push it to the front without creating a new VC?

I'm trying to search for the solutions but I don't know which keyword to begin with.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: No, this is the same VC1, the problems may be in your didAppear/willAppear methods. Share the code of VC1 please

Comment: Thanks. I got the problem. You are right. Before using tabbar, I use some code to update UI when pushing from navigation controller. Now I change the flow back. It works as in your guess. I'm so happy then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior of UITabBarController is to hold references to the tabs (the ViewControllers) in it´s `viewControllers` property. If you switch back and forth the `viewDidAppear()` method is called on the ViewController for the selected tab.

The controllers managed by a UITabBarController will be allocated while the TabController is allocated. After that it will use the same instances of the controllers.

You may update some UI in `viewDidAppear`?

For reference: [UITabBarController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller)